# Changing URL in string to clickable link while changing its value

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a little webapp, I'm using JS to change a url inside a string to a clickable url, while changing the url to say 'tap here'. The problem however is if I keep the URl the same, without changing it to 'tap here' it all works fine. But if I change it, the clickable link links to an error page:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /client/http://www.google.com'
>   target='_blank'>tap here was not found on this server.

Here's the code I'm using that works (without changing to 'tap here')

```
 $('.discussion').ready(function(){

    $('.discussion #messages p').each(function(){

      var str = $(this).html();

        var regex = /(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/ig

        var replaced_text = str.replace(regex, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");

        $(this).html(replaced_text);


   });
});
```

And this is the one I want to work, but gives the error:

```
$('.discussion').ready(function(){

    $('.discussion #messages p').each(function(){

      var str = $(this).html();

        var regex = /(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/ig

        var replaced_text = str.replace(regex, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>tap here</a>");

        $(this).html(replaced_text);


   });
});
```

[EDIT] and here's the HTML

```
<ol class="discussion" scroll-bottom="replies">
    <div ng-class="getClass($index)" ng-repeat="reply in replies track by $index">
      <li ng-repeat="item in reply.text.replace('?','.').replace('!','.').split('. ') track by $index" class="fix-clutter">
        <div class="avatar">
          <img ng-src="{{reply.avatar}}">
        </div>

        <div id="messages" class="animated slideInUp">

          <p class="animated fadeInUp">{{item}}</p>

        </div>
       </li>
    </div>
  </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/CK2vJdeIxtN1Bvt7Kce5?p=preview with the following HTML:

```
<div class="discussion">
  <div id="messages">
    <p>
      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395188/changing
    </p>
    <p>
      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395188/changing
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything works pretty well on this specific scenario. Can you paste your HTML?
However the regex it's not working right. If you add "dashes" on your URI, The regex fail to get the full URI and it breaks on the dash.

Update:
I checked again... and the problem is 90% caused by the regex rule.

Another case where is breaking is when you have already on your html the link with the "href tag" as the code below:

```
<div class="discussion">
  <div id="messages">
    <p>
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395188/changing'>LINK</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tnx for your time, I've added the HTML. I don't have any links in the HTML, the data gets added through php.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help me a lot. I needed the sample data coming from php to fix the regex rule. By the way, I didn't know you were using Angular. At this point I would suggest you to move all this logic to a custom filter in AngularJS and apply that to **item** like: {{ item | myCustomFilter }}. (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)